# Send MapMyRun data to Runkeeper

Tags: migration

I've been using MapMyRun for a few years now, generally it's ok stats wise but is pretty horrible to use. So looking to move all my data from it to Runkeeper, is there a way this can be done?

Ideally it would be great if all the runs I have completed in MapMyRun are replicated in Runkeeper, is that even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tech, not sports

Comment: @studro Can it be moved to the correct stack rather than closed? It'll likely get more attention here than on some tech stack.

Answer (score 2):

I found this - https://www.fitnesssyncer.com/

It worked great, did all my runs separately including all the data and routes!